# Is using a transistor to prevent backfeed current a good practice?

Tags: transistors, current, diodes, usb, protection

first of all I'm a newbie in electronics,
With that said let's move onto the problem.

I have a circuit powered by an USB port with a **DSD TECH USB to TTL Serial Adapter with FTDI FT232RL Chip** from a computer motherboard,
i'd like to know if using a transistor like I did on the schematic
is a good practice to prevent current from flowing back into the motherboard.

I'd like to use a transistor [TIP33CG_2 on the diagram] (or any other method) to prevent a big voltage drop that a diode would give me
since I need a maximum voltage into the capacitors connected directly on VCC.

Here's the circuit diagram :
[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: You'll have even more voltage drop over that transistor than with a standard diode. Use a schottky diode and you'll likely be fine. Also, be aware that those supercaps will create a pretty large inrush current, which can cause issues with some USB hosts.

Comment: Which supercaps do you intend to use? _"...with FTDI FT232RL Chip **from a computer motherboard**"_ - what does this mean?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Klas Kenny.
For the supercaps those are some 1.5F 5.5V and the DSD TECH USB to TTL Serial Adapter with FTDI FT232RL Chip is basically a device to use an USB port like a serial port, to talk to the atmega328p and power it

Comment: What is DP8? Does it matter that it's clamped to a maximum of +0.7V?

Comment: @SimonFitch DP8 is to control a transistor to let the curent pass from an other circuit, but what do you mean clamped to +0.7v ? I don't understand where you got that value from

Comment: @Vincent I mean that the potential difference between a BJT's base and emitter cannot ever exceed 0.7V. TIP33CG_1's emitter is at 0V, so its base can never rise above +0.7V.

Comment: @SimonFitch to be honest I didn't even know that, DP8 provides a 5V digital signal to allow the current to pass through the loop you can see at the right of TIP33CG_1, the voltage potential between emitter and collector is +5v and the current is very small. If you know any better transistor to recommand go ahead I'll take every advice you'll give me

Comment: @Vincent, just a 4.7k resistor in series with the base (that is, between DP8 node and the base), and increase R1 to more like 10k. Or, better, replace TIP33CG_1 with a logic-level N-channel MOSFET (2N7000?) Both ideas would have the same effect, and both would permit any voltage at DP8.